# How to optimize this method in Scala?

Tags: scala, sequence, scala-option

Suppose I've got class `A` with method `foo`:

```
class A(x: Int) { def foo(): Option[Int] = if (x > 0) Some(x) else None }
```

Now I am writing function `bar` like this:

```
def bar(as: List[A]): Option[(A,  Int)] = for {
  a <- as.view.find(_.foo.nonEmpty)
  foo <- a.foo
} yield (a, foo)
```

The code above works fine but what it invokes the `foo` method *twice* for the found `A` instance. How to re-write `bar` to invoke method `foo` only *once* for the found `A` instance ?

Comment: `as.view.map(a => (a, a.foo)).find(_._2.nonEmpty).flatten`?

Comment: Make `foo` a `val` and pay the price of creating the value only once?

Comment: Not sure. I am afraid it's even more expensive.

Comment: More expensive to calculate it once? How so? Because you're retaining the value in memory?

Comment: Suppose my `as: List[A]` has 1000 instances and the 10th instance has `foo` not empty. Now `foo` is invoked 10 + 1 times. If I make `foo` a `val` it's invoked 1000 times. Am I missing something ?

Comment: `lazy val` then?

Comment: `lazy val` is probably Ok.  I just don't like it. Would prefer a solution without it.

Comment: @Bergi Does it compile ?

Comment: @Michael I have no idea, I don't even have a Scala compiler installed anywhere :-) It was just a quick guess, that's why it's a comment not an answer

Comment: @Bergi I see :)

Comment: Not sure why you don't like it, but making it a lazy val would probably require the least amount of code and conveys exactly what you're trying to do, lazily search for `Foo`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Well ... on the seconds thought I will try `lazy val`. Looks like we don't have any better solution right now. Thanks.

Comment: LazyList/Stream is your best choice here. It’s a lazy collection which will cache all the items visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 as.iterator.flatMap { a => a.foo.map { a -> _ } }.find(_ => true)
```

Comment: Does it always iterate over the _whole_ list instead of stopping when it finds the required instance ?

Comment: no, it doesn't. Iterators are lazy, like views, just less ... weird.

Comment: Does it compile ? Looks like `Iterator` does not have method `headOption`.

Comment: I got `<console>:15: error: value headOption is not a member of Iterator[(A, Int)]`

Comment: Oops ... indeed. That's weird. Ok, how about now?

Comment: There are two solutions in the comment :) They all work to your requirements, so, I am not sure which one is "better" , and how you define the criteria to figuring it out. Personally, I am not a fun of views and (to a lesser extent) of for-comprehensions (and also constructs like `_._2` make me cringe), and explicit checks for `Option.nonEmpty` aren't very idiomatic, so, I prefer this one :) Using (lazy) val instead of `def` seems fine too ... but that one you don't like for some reason, so ..

Comment: I meant the solution of @Bergi which, as it's turns out, does not compile.

Comment: BTW I am ok with `view`, for-comprehension, `_._2`, and all that scala stuff.

Comment: Well ... good for you :D I am "ok" with it too ... It's just error prone and not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use streams. The elements in stream are evaluated lazily.

```
def bar(as: List[A]): Option[(A, Int)] = {
  as
    .toStream
    .map(x => (x, x.foo()))
    .find(z => z._2.isDefined)
    .map(p => (p._1, p._2.get))
}
```